# Unable to open WireShark in CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, wireshark, centos6.5

I have installed WireShark in CentOS 6.5 with the following packages using Yum.

```
 Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package               Arch         Version                 Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 wireshark             x86_64       1.8.10-8.el6_6          updates        11 M
 wireshark-devel       x86_64       1.8.10-8.el6_6          updates       905 k
 wireshark-gnome       x86_64       1.8.10-8.el6_6          updates       855 k
Installing for dependencies:
 glib2-devel           x86_64       2.28.8-4.el6            base          299 k
 libsmi                x86_64       0.4.8-4.el6             base          2.4 M
Updating for dependencies:
 glib2                 i686         2.28.8-4.el6            base          1.7 M
 glib2                 x86_64       2.28.8-4.el6            base          1.7 M
```

When I tried to open it, I'm getting this error

```
[root@localhost ~]# wireshark 
wireshark: symbol lookup error: wireshark: undefined symbol: gtk_combo_box_text_new_with_entry
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Could someone help me to resolve this ?

Comment: try running ldconfig first

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just tried it, getting same error message.

Answer (score 10):

This is a [bug/issue](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.scientific.user/7224) with the gtk2 version in EL6.5.

The current version in your distribution is: gtk2-2.20.1-4.el6.x86_64, but gtk2-2.24 is needed for gtk_combo_box_text_new_with_entry.

You can probably just `yum update gtk2` to get the version from CentOS 6.6 (or update your entire system) to get things working.

Comment: heads up - update gtk2 can take a little while ..

Comment: yum update gtk worked like a charm. And was not so long. :)